# MFP 7.1 Disable Direct Update?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have an app migrated from WL 6.1 where I used to disable in WLClient.js. I have tried to disable with the Console but I still get an update after invoking custom auth.

The app is downloaded from enterprise MF appcenter. I have seen the security test way of disabling, but I'm not sure I can do this since the conversion and it is default.

```
wl.realm.expiration.directUpdate=-1
wl.realm.expiration.remoteDisable=300
wl.realm.expiration.deviceAutoProvisioning=-1
wl.realm.expiration.deviceNoProvisioning=-1
wl.realm.expiration.antiXSRF=-1
wl.realm.expiration.authenticity=-1
wl.realm.expiration.anonymousUser=-1


    <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1" mode="disabled"/>
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SubscribeServlet"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
    <customSecurityTest name="AgentSecurityTest">
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="disabled"/>
        <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="FbitnAgentRealm"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
```

[image]

```
11-09 11:22:02.665 2328-2344/? D/NONE: deleteOldSubmitted -- NOT removing: Test  1510248094325
11-09 11:22:02.671 2328-2344/? D/NONE: main.js: returning pendingRecordCount = 2
11-09 11:22:02.677 2328-2344/? D/NONE: App.getRequireWifi --requireWifi was NOT undefined or null in localStorage. state=false
11-09 11:22:02.683 2328-2344/? D/NONE: App.getRequireWifi - navigator reports connection type as: 4g
11-09 11:22:02.689 2328-2344/? D/NONE: Current connection state is: NOT WIFI
11-09 11:22:02.694 2328-2344/? D/NONE: pageLayout.onRender: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Pixel Build/OPR3.170623.008; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36/Worklight/7.1.0.0
11-09 11:22:02.699 2328-2344/? D/NONE: listItem.js formatted submit dttm: 11/9/2017, 11:21:34 AM
11-09 11:22:07.321 2328-2344/? D/NONE: main.js connection (type: 4g)
11-09 11:22:07.338 2328-2344/? D/NONE: App.processPending - col name: PSRecordCollection
11-09 11:22:07.353 2328-2344/? D/NONE: PSLocalStore.get cacheType is JSONStore
11-09 11:22:07.368 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getLoggedInUser >
11-09 11:22:07.381 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.isSessionExpired >
11-09 11:22:07.389 2328-2344/? E/NONE: Unknown realm [******AgentRealm]. null returned for key: isUserAuthenticated
11-09 11:22:07.398 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.isSessionExpired user is not authenicated in realm. Checking longer term session....
11-09 11:22:07.406 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getStoredCredentials >
11-09 11:22:07.414 2328-2344/? D/NONE: PSLocalStore.get cacheType is JSONStore
11-09 11:22:07.423 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getStoredCredentials about to get collection, find id=1 and return the results.
11-09 11:22:07.431 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getStoredCredentials collection returned is: not null and not undefined type is: object
11-09 11:22:07.438 2328-2344/? D/NONE: calling findAll on JSONStore_PSLocalStoreCollection.
11-09 11:22:07.445 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getStoredCredentials: after get/find
11-09 11:22:07.452 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getStoredCredentials <
11-09 11:22:07.458 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.isSessionExpired <
11-09 11:22:07.464 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getLoggedInUser <
11-09 11:22:07.471 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getStoredCredentials found userdata in psLocalStore. id:1. results len:0
11-09 11:22:07.477 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.getStoredCredentials: did not find userdata for id:1.
11-09 11:22:07.483 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.isSessionExpiredno longer term session data available. It is null.
11-09 11:22:07.489 2328-2344/? D/NONE: EmployeeApp.html.hideBusyIndicator -- hiding
11-09 11:22:07.494 2328-2344/? D/NONE: App.processPending --failed to obtain a valid user id. Will notify GUI that login needs to occur.
11-09 11:22:07.499 2328-2344/? D/NONE: EmployeeApp.html.hideBusyIndicator -- hiding
11-09 11:22:07.503 2328-2344/? D/NONE: deleteOldSubmitted -- deleting records successfully submitted before: 1507656127423 10/10/2017, 12:22:07 PM
11-09 11:22:07.508 2328-2344/? D/NONE: deleteOldSubmitted -- NOT removing: Test  1510248094325
11-09 11:22:07.513 2328-2344/? D/NONE: main.js: returning pendingRecordCount = 2
11-09 11:22:07.519 2328-2344/? D/NONE: App.getRequireWifi --requireWifi was NOT undefined or null in localStorage. state=false
11-09 11:22:07.524 2328-2344/? D/NONE: App.getRequireWifi - navigator reports connection type as: 4g
11-09 11:22:07.530 2328-2344/? D/NONE: Current connection state is: NOT WIFI
11-09 11:22:07.535 2328-2344/? D/NONE: pageLayout.onRender: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; Pixel Build/OPR3.170623.008; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36/Worklight/7.1.0.0
11-09 11:22:07.541 2328-2344/? D/NONE: listItem.js formatted submit dttm: 11/9/2017, 11:21:34 AM
11-09 11:22:11.019 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.doClientLogin >
11-09 11:22:11.025 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.doClientLogin realm:******AgentRealm
11-09 11:22:11.032 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.doClientLogin setting interactive login flag.
11-09 11:22:11.038 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.doClientLogin cordova connection info: 4g
11-09 11:22:11.046 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.doClientLogin- isNetworkConnected:true type:boolean
11-09 11:22:11.054 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.doClientLogin -- Network is connected. Check server availability.
11-09 11:22:11.063 2328-2344/? D/NONE: EmployeeApp.html.showBusyIndicator -- showing
11-09 11:22:11.070 2328-2344/? D/NONE: establishSSLClientAuth
11-09 11:22:11.076 2328-2344/? D/NONE: agentAuthChallengeHandler.doClientLogin <
11-09 11:22:11.091 2328-2344/? D/NONE: establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
11-09 11:22:11.101 2328-2344/? D/NONE: Request [/apps/services/api/EmployeeApp/android/init]
11-09 11:22:11.220 2328-2432/? W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getWlSignedClientId blocked the main thread for 116ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
11-09 11:22:11.222 2328-2333/? I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=239KB, data=216KB
11-09 11:22:11.222 2328-2333/? I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=228KB, data=178KB
11-09 11:22:11.274 2328-2344/? D/NONE: EmployeeApp.html.hideBusyIndicator -- hiding
11-09 11:22:11.282 2328-2344/? D/HttpPostRequestSender: WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:42 :: Sending request https://************/******MobileAgent/apps/services/api/EmployeeApp/android/init
11-09 11:22:11.288 2328-2344/? D/NONE: controllers/layoutController -- handling layout:login.
11-09 11:22:11.497 2328-3406/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
11-09 11:24:22.212 2328-2333/? I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=251KB, data=188KB
11-09 11:24:22.213 2328-2333/? I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=251KB, data=188KB
11-09 11:24:22.213 2328-2333/? I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
11-09 11:26:06.210 2328-2344/? D/NONE: Request [/apps/services/api/EmployeeApp/android/heartbeat]
11-09 11:26:06.227 2328-2432/? W/PluginManager: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin.getWlSignedClientId blocked the main thread for 23ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
11-09 11:26:06.293 2328-2344/? D/HttpPostRequestSender: WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:42 :: Sending request https://************/******MobileAgent/apps/services/api/EmployeeApp/android/heartbeat
11-09 11:31:06.166 2328-2344/? D/NONE: Request [/apps/services/api/EmployeeApp/android/heartbeat]
11-09 11:31:06.243 2328-2344/? D/HttpPostRequestSender: WLHybridRequestSender.run in WLHybridRequestSender.java:42 :: Sending request https://************/******MobileAgent/apps/services/api/EmployeeApp/android/heartbeat
11-09 11:35:28.205 2328-2344/? D/WLClient: WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivitySaveInstanceState in WLClient.java:1520 :: on activity save instance state com.EmployeeApp.EmployeeApp
11-09 11:35:28.213 2328-2344/? D/WLClient: WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityPaused in WLClient.java:1508 :: on activity paused com.EmployeeApp.EmployeeApp . activity count = 0
11-09 11:35:28.225 2328-2344/? D/NONE: Flush called
11-09 11:35:29.308 2328-2344/? D/WLClient: WLClient$ActivityListener.onActivityStopped in WLClient.java:1532 :: on activity stopped com.EmployeeApp.EmployeeApp
11-09 11:35:34.321 2328-2335/? I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ObjectsAllocated
11-09 11:35:34.415 2328-2335/? I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 94.459ms for cause ObjectsAllocated
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2014/12/30/customizing-direct-update/ for how to customise or disable direct update post 6.1

Comment: I have added this to my authconfig, but still get update.                                              <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
            <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1" mode="disabled"/>
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SubscribeServlet"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
        <customSecurityTest name="AgentSecurityTest">
            <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1" mode="disabled"/>
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="FbitnAgentRealm"/>

        </customSecurityTest>